# Modified Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\Gamma$ denote the positively oriented circle of radius $2$ with center at the
origin. Let $f$ be an analytic function on $\{z \in\mathbb C : |z| > 1\}$, and let
$$\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z) = 0$$
Prove that
$$f(z) =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(\zeta)}{z-\zeta}$$

for all $z \in\mathbb C$ with $|z| > 2.$

I tried to define a function $g(z)=f(1/z)$ and apply Cauchy Integral Formula on $g$, but could not come up with anything.

Comment: $g(z)$ has a removable singularity as $z=0$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820768/prove-that-fz-frac12-pi-i-int-gamma-fracf-zetaz-zeta-d-zeta?noredirect=1&lq=1